# Dialogfragment onCreateDialog NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to load DialogFragment, but I sometimes get null on onCreateDialog. I'm not sure when it's happening, but not very rarely. How can I solve this?

Utils.java

```
    currentDialog = PopupDialog.newInstance(type, title, maString, isCancelable);
    currentDialog.show(ft, "dialog");
```

PopupDialog.java

```
public class PopupDialog extends DialogFragment{


public static final int POPUP_ERROR = 0;
public static final int POPUP_WARNNING = 1;

private int type;
private String title;
private String messageString;
private boolean isCancelable;

public static PopupDialog newInstance(int type,String title,String maString,boolean isCancelable) {
    PopupDialog f = new PopupDialog();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("type",type);
    args.putString("title", title);
    args.putString("maString", maString);
    args.putBoolean("isCancelable", isCancelable);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle arg = getArguments();
    type = arg.getInt("type");
    title = arg.getString("title");
    messageString = arg.getString("maString");
    isCancelable = arg.getBoolean("isCancelable");
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE,0);
    if (!isCancelable){
        setCancelable(false);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_error, container, false);

    TextView popupTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.popupTitle);
    popupTitle.setText(title);

    TextView popupMessage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.popupMessage);
    popupMessage.setText(messageString);

    ImageView popupIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.popupIcon);
    messageString = messageString + "\n";
    if(type == POPUP_ERROR){
        messageString = messageString + getString(R.string.error_default_ext);
        popupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_error);
    }
    else{
        popupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.warning_icon);
    }

    popupMessage.setText(messageString);


    Button okButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.okButton);       

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new dismissDialogOnClick());

    if (!isCancelable){
        okButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return v;
}

@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return d; 
 }
```

EDIT:

Attached the stack trace. If i'm trying to do getDialog onCreateDialog (like first case, it doesn't happen always

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.DialogFragment.onActivityCreated(DialogFragment.java:469)
    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1703)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

getDialog returns the Dialog object after the internal show is called. Calling it in onCreateView is too early. You can override `onCreateDialog`, retrive the object returned by the super class, and call the method on this object

```
@Override 
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog d = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return d; 
 }
```

Comment: Now i'm getting null exception instead on DialogFragment class on created function. i guess it was too easy :)

Comment: it is not related. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I posted the stack on first message

Comment: can you update your question with the changes you made to your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can call getDialog() only when the dialog is shown. You could register an "on shown listener" on your alert dialog to get a reference of the dialog.